# Bot doesn't collect giveaway duration, value error (discord-giveaways | ms)

Tags: javascript, async-await, bots, discord.js

[image]So because the the command first only worked when i put every option in 1 message ".sg #bot-test 1m 1 Test", that worked with args, but now i am trying to let the bot await the options from the user like you will see in the screenshot, but when it comes to the duration he gives me the error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: val is not a non-empty string or a valid number. val={"channelID":"702608643329228821","deleted":false,"id":"710388381846077511","type":"DEFAULT","content":"2d","authorID":"391243477058584588","pinned":false,"tts":false,"nonce":"710388377081348096","system":false,"embeds":[],"attachments":[],"createdTimestamp":1589440188610,"editedTimestamp":null,"webhookID":null,"applicationID":null,"activity":null,"flags":0,"reference":null,"guildID":"672002616372363274","cleanContent":"2d"}`

I would not know what i should change, https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-giveaways, if you want to see how the package "works".

The part of my code:

```
await message.channel.send(`Please provide a duration for the giveaway!`)
            const Messagefilter2 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                let giveawayDuration;
                await message.channel.awaitMessages(Messagefilter2, { max: 1, }).then((collected) => {
                    // Giveaway duration
                    giveawayDuration = collected.first()
                })
            // If the duration isn't valid
            if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))){
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid duration!');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error only was because I forgot to add `.content` so it should be `if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration.content))){`